# How to query Haystack to get similar items

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I am trying to ge similar posts when a post ID is sent as a payload to an endpoint (RESTful API) using Haystack and ElasticSearch:

```
original_post = Article.objects.get(id=pk) #pk is 2 for example
related_items = SearchQuerySet().more_like_this(original_post.title)
result = related_items[0].object.title

print(result)
```

This throws an Error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

I am new to Elastic Search. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error indicates that you have a variable expectied to be a `QuerySet` but containing a string value. Debuf how `SearchQuerySet()` evaluates.

Answer (score 0):

```
related_items = SearchQuerySet().more_like_this(original_post)
```

See function definition in [haystack docs](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html#SearchQuerySet.more_like_this):

> SearchQuerySet.more_like_this(self, model_instance)

So it's expected that you'll pass model_instance into `more_like_this`, not a string.

Comment: It threw an error with `The model <class 'posts.models.Article'> is not registered`

Comment: It returned `UserWarning: The model <class 'posts.models.Article'> is not registered for search.`

Comment: @kinGKong Well, it seems that you do not have `Articles` index in elasticsearch: 
https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/blob/4910ccb01c31d12bf22dcb000894eece6c26f74b/haystack/utils/loading.py#L350

Try to `python manage.py rebuild_index` and search again. If this won't work, please add to your question how you're defining indexes.

Comment: I think the issue arises because I don't have an index defined. Please, should the Article index be created in the models or written in a singular script?

Comment: @kinGKong Sure, you need to create `ArticleIndex` class, people usually create `search_indexes.py` inside app, this is proper place. See https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#handling-data You have to define something similar to `NoteIndex`. But anyway, this is different question from your original.

Comment: Thanks @Satevg, I've done that...but getting a `AttributeError: 'Elasticsearch' object has no attribute 'mlt'` Do I need to downgrade my elasticsearch? currently using v2.8.1

Comment: @kinGKong Yep, I can google same problem: https://github.com/kezabelle/django-haystackbrowser/issues/15 or https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/issues/1398 You should downgrade, but I can't say to what version exactly (never used mlt feature by myself).